# two-level select fields in Django form

Tags: django

I have a two fields `category` and `subcategory`, like below

```
CATEGORY = {
             'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Watermelon'],
             'Cell': ['Sumsung', 'Apple', 'Huawei'],
             'OS': ['OS X', 'IOS', 'Android', 'Linux']
           }
```

So the category is `['Fruit', 'Cell Brand', 'OS']` and each of has its own subcategory.

Now I have the form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('category', 'subcategory')
    category = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select)
    subcategory = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance  = kwargs.get('instance', '')
        self.data  = kwargs.get('data', '')
        self.category_choice = CATEGORY
        self.fields['category'].widget.choice  = self.init_category()
        self.fields['category'].widget.attrs['data-choices'] = self.category_choice
        self.fields['subcategory'].widget.choice = self.init_subcategory()

    def init_category(self):
        cat_lst = sorted([key for key in self.category_choice])
        return ((key, key) for key in cat_lst) 

    def init_subcategory(self):
        if not self.instance:
            return ((key, key) for key in self.category_choice['Cell'])
        elif not self.instance.category:
            return ((key, key) for key in self.category_choice[self.data['category']])
        return ((key, key) for key in self.category_choice[self.instance.category])
```

I want to explain a little bit about 'init_subcategory' method, it looks very ugly to me. Generally I want to initiate the subcategory choice by category value. There are three cases: 1. create a new form: this should be an unbounded form I suppose, then I return the first item's subcategory which is `Cell`. 2. edit a form, so we should render the category and subcategory using the values stored in the instance. 3. form returned with error, in this case there should be data bounded to the form.

Since I already pass the `CATEGORY` to front end, I can use javascript to manipulate the subcategory field choice according to the category field change.

So my question is, is there a better way to implement what I want here? Or are there any improvements here. Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think you should have any `subcategory` logic in the form, you should only provide all the choices and let javascript do the rest of the work. Also your field `category` and `subcategory` definition is funny, you should use `forms.ChoiceField` and update `choices` parameter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield

Comment: @ShangWang Thanks, if I only have `category` field, then what should I use to update `choices` parameter, `(('Fruit', 'Fruit'), ('Cell', 'Cell'), ('OS', 'OS'))` ?